# SQL Server 2008 update License

Tags: sql-server, update, sql-server-2008-r2, licensing

How can I change my SQL Server 2008 license? I have the Enterprise Edition installed with a 90-day key and it will expire on 7 days. Two months ago, I purchased the final one but I don't know how to install/change to the new one.

Is there a legal way to do it or  I have to uninstall completely the application and reinstall it with the new license? I don't want to do that because I already have setup some stuff on the current instance.

Saludos,
Leo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the responses in this forum posting will [help](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/960543ca-cc47-446d-80eb-b4d61a585930).

If the link is no longer available:

One suggestion was:

1)   Upgrading from trial Edition prior to the end of the period
To perform an in-place upgrade of SQL 2008 trial edition to other SQL Server 2008 full blown editions, simply run the setup and it will identify the existing installation, and will run an upgrade check. It will then let you know if the upgrade is possible or not. If the upgrade path is supported, simply go through the setup wizard and it will automatically upgrade the already installed instance of trial edition.

2)   Upgrade from trial Edition 2008 after it has expired
You need to uninstall the trial version of SQL Server 2008 Edition before installing the fully licensed version of the other editions.

Second suggestion was:

Step 1: Run the SQL Server setup.exe again.

Step 2: In the SQL Server Installation Center, click "Maintenance" on the left navigation bar. On the right pane, click Edition Upgrade.

Step 3: Go through the wizard and you'll be able to enter the license key.

Verified by upgrading a SQL Server 2008 Instance from Enterprise Evaluation to Enterprise

---

Have to note that the first person's suggestion was by someone who was labeled as "Microsoft Contingent Staff".

Comment: Thanks... The issue is that the installed version is the Enterprise version and I only require to change the license. Also, I can't uninstall it as I have a production application using the DB continuously...I might stop it for a few minutes but no more than 20 or 30 minutes.... Any further ideas?

Comment: @Leo: given the bind you're in, I'd definitely call Microsoft for guidance and support.

Comment: Thanks Michael..I'm stuck and calling is more frustrating than posting a message on a forumm.... DEFINITELY, MSFT should have better support for this...

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased a permanent Enterprise Edition key then you just need to run the Edition Upgrade and provide the new key, but if you purchased a Standard edition key then you will have to uninstall and reinstall from Standard Edition media.